# Javascript folder disappears when modifying URL

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a page on Google App Engine which loads a local javascript file, but when change the URL, from `myapp.appspot.com/form` to `myapp.appspot.com/form/12345` when I want to get something from the database, it's not able to load the local javascript from my static folder anymore.

Here's the router

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/form/?', FormHandler),
    ('/form/([0-9]+)', FormHandler)
], debug=True)
```

My javascript files are called`<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` and are stored in a static folder called 'js' which is added to my app.yaml file. Still get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I can't wrap my head around this. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your yaml file to see urls for static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute URL instead of a relative one. I.e.,

```
<script src=/js/jquery-1.10.1.min-js"></script>
```

Note the leading `/`. Without that, your `/form` page will request `/form/js/jquery...`